# Finding the set "max_result_window" for Elastic Search index?

Tags: elasticsearch

So when querying ElasticSearch, I know you can constrain the size with the "size" parameter. By default, it's 10,000. I was wondering how to know what's the max (if it has been changed from 10,000)?

I have tried "/index/_settings" in hopes of finding the max_window_size, but couldn't find anything. I'm not necessarily sure if that's because it doesn't have a limit at all, or if I am doing something wrong.

So to rephrase my question: I basically want to know how to find the max size when trying to query "size: xx" to an elastic search server. If the size is 10,000/the default, then I want to know where I can find this number.

Any tips or guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value isn't specified on the index itself (in _settings where you were looking), then it is 10000. You can change this setting only on the index itself as far as I know. To automatically apply it to new indices you can use [an index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings).

It appears to be an oversight by the devs to me, if you use rolling indices by date for example then there is no single index for you to query modifications to the value from (sure you could guess one). I think you just have to make sure to match your query code assumptions to your index template. In my opinion there should be a way to just ask for max results possible without needing to know that value beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that elastic search default max query size is 10000. The way to get more is to use the "scroll" api:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll

This essentially uses pagination to split your result into user defined segments and allows you to "scroll" to the next one using a "Scroll_id" that's returned from the initial query.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. Unforunately, this isn't what I'm looking for. I was wondering how can I get the max elastic search limit? (An integer, not results).